# Handling Full Text Permutations SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

We have a database table that holds a list of countries and basic information about them, that we use Full Text Indexing to return data to the user through a web app. I am looking into country names and the different permutations (spellings) that are possible. I will use the below country for instance.

St. Martin
Saint Martin
St. Marteen
Sint Maarten

As you can see, depending on the regions, the user can enter any one of those requests and expect to get the same result. I imagine to allow this to work, I lookup table of sorts is needed be able to perform the contains() against. I just wanted to know if there is a blog post, or "Best Practices" way to go about doing this.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try customizing the thesaurus file. See [Configure and Manage Thesaurus Files for Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx).